# Where do bounced messages from sendmail end up?

Tags: php, sendmail

I have a public intranet (called internet) that is password protected that used by our employees.  We have a feature where one can send an article to a customer for example.  That being said, the marketing department, if they wish other employees to be made aware of it, they send an email to a group, such as sales-international@company.tld for example, and some people have mentioned they don't receive it.

If this is the case, how do I see the log file when a message gets bounced?

I can obviously use sendmail from a root shell and it immediately bounces back from mailer-daemon but how can I do such activities if apache is sending the message, not root?

I should mention the send message is from within the webpage itself, not using his email client.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the configuration file for syslog on the system hosting the apache instance, it should be `/etc/syslog.conf` if you have a standard installation.  Look where the `mail` stuff is logged.

If you have root access, you can change the mail log specification to `mail.debug`, which will give you a ton of information on sendmail's behavior.  Make sure you understand the `syslog.conf` format before making changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can install a network monitor on your server and scrutinize the process and traffic.
Then you find it is caused by slow response of the server/application or the destine unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I couldn't figure out how to add my original account, I probably used the wrong openID page.

Regardless, I am jweinraub too.

Anyway, do I modify the above, or do I add somehting like

mail.debug       /var/log/mail.debug.log  as well?